# Por que as font-face não funcionam de um pc para outro?

Tags: html, css, html5, font

Olá!
Criei um site em um computador com fontes externas, utilizando a tag @font-face. Porém, quando fui abrir o documento html em outro pc, o arquivo não carregou as fontes.

Coloquei o font-face e a classe pra chamar ele no html

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Bebas Neue'), url('BebasNeue.eot') format('eot');
}

.div02 {
    font-family: Bebas Neue;
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar?
Obrigada.

Comment: Acredito que ou o navegador do segundo pc está desatualizado ou não tem suporte para isso

Comment: Utilizei o Google Chrome no processo e ele está atualizado.

Comment: Coloque o código fonte do font-face

Comment: Você passou o arquivo do `@font-face`?

Comment: @LeticiaQueiroz seja bem-vinda, para saber como funciona a **comunidade** faça o [tour]. Como você está abrindo esse arquivo ? Copiou todos os arquivos? Favor [**edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/294465/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Coloquei o font-face e a classe pra chamar ele no html: 
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bebas Neue'), url('BebasNeue.eot') format('eot');
}

.div02 {
font-family: Bebas Neue;
}

Answer (score 1):

Leticia tem alguns detalhes no seu código que vc precisa corrigir.

O primeiro é que vc precisa declarar o nome do Font Family dentro de aspas na `.div02`

```
.div02 {
    font-family: "Bebas Neue"; /* repare o nome entre aspas */
}
```

Agora sobre o `@font-face` na declaração local() vc não colocou a extenção da fonte, no seu caso `.eot` e também tinha deixado um espaço entre uma palavra e outro repare "Bebas Neue" / "BebasNeue".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    src: local('BebasNeue.eot'), 
         url('BebasNeue.eot') format('eot');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Por fim certifique-se se a sua fonte que está no seu servidor realmente está no formato *.EOT*, se ela for *.TTF* e vc estiver declarando *.EOT* ela não vai ser carregada. Vc pode conferir isso no *Chrome DevTools* na aba `Network > Font` e ver se a font foi baixada.

Vc pode fazer um *fallback* caso o formato `.EOT` não seja encontrado, colocando dois formatos de font diferente no CSS. Veja abaixo como fica. **OBS:** A o browser vai tentar sempre encontrar primeiro a fonte que é declarada antes, ou seja de cima para baixo.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue";
  src: url("BebasNeue.eot") format("eot"),
       url("BebasNeue.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Artigo que pode te ajudar https://tableless.com.br/font-face-fonts-externas-na-web/